# How to pass the value of the text box to the disabled text box using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having the text box where we will enter the value in the text box and while entering the value needs to be added to the disabled text box using javascript

Thanks,
Vara Prasad.M

Comment: actually i am using the textchanged event in C#

Comment: All the more reason we need code to be able to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to change the disabled input **as you enter text**, a server side solution is definitely not the right move because posting back in real time is not feasible. Here's something client side using jQuery:

```
$("#abledtextbox").live({
    keyup: function(){
        $("#disabledtextbox").val($(this).val())
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

can you use jQuery?

```
$("#idOfSecondTextbox").blur( function() {
  $(#idOfSecondTextBox).val( $("#idOfFirstTextBox").val() );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't ask for jQuery, here's a plain JavaScript solution:

```
function setValue(inputId, value)
{
    document.getElementById(inputId).value = value;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<input id="text1"
    onkeyup="setValue('text2', this.value)"
    onchange="setValue('text2', this.value)" />
<input id="text2" />
```